# How can I maintain type narrowing inside Array.find method?

Tags: typescript

In the following code snippet, I'm receiving the following typescript compilation error within the Array.find method. I would expect that my type is narrowed given the `if` statement checking that `context.params.id` is not `undefined`.

Is there a reason this type is losing its narrowing within the find method? What options do I have to successfully narrow this type?

> TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```js
type Book = {
  id: number;
}

const books: Book[] = [];

type Context = {
  response: {
    body: any;
  },
  params?: {
    id?: string
  }
}

const handler = (context: Context) => {
  if (context.params && context.params.id) {
    context.response.body = books.find(
      (book) => book.id === parseInt(context.params.id) // Error
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to assign `context.params.id` to a new variable outside of `find` callback.

```
const handler = (context: Context) => {
  if (context.params && context.params.id) {
    const id = parseInt(context.params.id);
    context.response.body = books.find(
      (book) => book.id === id // OK
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Ah interesting. I like that approach. Any idea why the narrowing is otherwise lost within the `find` method?

Comment: It's not lost withing the find function, it's lost everywhere. Typescript can not be sure that the variable won't change between null check and using it somewhere later. You will get the same error even if you do `let  id = parseInt(context.params.id);` with `let` instead of `const`. I would do `const id = context?.params?.id` at the beginning of the function and use it inside the if and find blocks.

Comment: @ritaj it seems to be fine using let: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG5MBfTTAYzhIGdgoqFEXYvCQBtALqooExplCQoAYU7AIAD15osOWhC5hOXCMW04+cfCGIBDEiEY4mAGmxQw12tYpcA-Cdc4BH5QPLS4JADmriws7Ia8ABa2+AA2dFIAFBwkqhrEyjnqwACUqAB8GK64AGZQWSpFAHTunt5QAGTtUNm5wM0eXlyNBKWmOGm8BFItRgCSOfWFGv2tQyMOZj1NuvqGEI38llL8SEPV4fgZAWYZJ4ilKBV3w-ioKGhTAPSfUADyANLXYobGL0IA

Comment: I had it a bit different: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nA1lAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG5MBfTTAYzhIGdgoqFEXYvCQBtALqooExplCQoAYU7AIAD15osOWhC5hOXCMW04+cfCGIBDEiEY4mAGmxQw12tYpcA-Cdc4BH5QPLS4JADmriws7Ia8ABa2+AA2dFIAFBwkqhrEyjnqwACUqAB8GK5pvARS2bnAPgB07p7ezQQOeABmUBkEpaY49UVNuvqGEE38llL8SFxN3eH4GQFmGfOIpSgVW021KEduHkYAkjn9+KUA9DdQAKK0tHC068VdMbKsmEA